# How to show multiple selected with asp.net mvc 3 and ListBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this VM properties

```
  public IList<Guid> SelectedEligiableCategories { get; set; }
  public IList<SelectListItem> EligiableCategories { get; set; }
```

I have this helpers in my view

```
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EligibleCategoryFrmVm.SelectedEligiableCategories, "Eligible Categories:")
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => Model.EligibleCategoryFrmVm.SelectedEligiableCategories, Model.EligibleCategoryFrmVm.EligiableCategories, new { @class = "eligibleCategoryListBox" })
```

I have this code in my controller

```
  List<SelectListItem> eligibleCategoriesListItems = Mapper.Map<List<EligibleCategory>, List<SelectListItem>>(eligibleCategories);
  foreach (var rewardTier in creditCard.RewardTiers)
        {
            CbRewardTierFrmVm rewardTierFrmVm = new CbRewardTierFrmVm();
            rewardTierFrmVm.EligibleCategoryFrmVm.EligiableCategories = eligibleCategoriesListItems;

            foreach (var ec in rewardTier.EligibleCategories)
            {
                rewardTierFrmVm.EligibleCategoryFrmVm.SelectedEligiableCategories.Add(ec.Id);
            }

            vm.CbRewardTierFrmVm.Add(rewardTierFrmVm);
        }
```

Yet when I load up my view. None of values for my ListBox are selected. I am not sure why. If this was a selectList this would work as it would match up the SelectedEligiableCategories to the value in the list.

I am not sure if this is because there is multiple selects

**Edit**

```
<select name="CbRewardTierFrmVm[63b504c0-0f9a-47ba-a8ff-db85f48d5f0f].EligibleCategoryFrmVm.SelectedEligiableCategories" multiple="multiple" id="CbRewardTierFrmVm_63b504c0-0f9a-47ba-a8ff-db85f48d5f0f__EligibleCategoryFrmVm_SelectedEligiableCategories" data-val-required="Must choose at least one eligible category." data-val="true" class="eligibleCategoryListBox ui-wizard-content ui-helper-reset ui-state-default" style="display: none;">
   <option value="ed2bb5f9-4565-4f69-ab15-9fca011c0692">Gas</option>
</select>
```

Do you think it is because I am using http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ ?

**Edit2**

I gone ahead and make an example. I must be missing something(not sure what). When I use "Darin Dimitrov" it works.

I switched the example to a dropdown as I am getting the same problem with it as well.

In this example I am not using a viewmodel since my initial assumption was somehow the helper I was using from Steven Sanders might be effecting it so I was going off his example.

This does not seem to be the case as I removed it and still get this problem.

```
  public class Gift
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
    }


 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>
        {

              new SelectListItem {Value = "",Text ="--"},
              new SelectListItem {Value = "1",Text ="1"},
              new SelectListItem {Value = "2",Text ="2"},
        };


        var initialData = new[] {
            new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95, Items = items, SelectedItem = "2" },
            new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00, Items = items, SelectedItem = "1"  }
         };

        return View("Index3",initialData);
    }

@model IList<EditorDemo.Models.Gift>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index3";
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x[i].SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model[i].Items, "Value", "Text")) 
}
```

It seems to not be able to handle when you put it in forloop and try it make more than one dropdown list.

Comment: I have a complete sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-the-DropDownList-67f9367d

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following works for me.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<Guid> SelectedEligiableCategories { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> EligiableCategories { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            SelectedEligiableCategories = new[]
            {
                // preselect the second and the fourth item
                new Guid("35830042-3556-11E1-BCDC-A6184924019B"),
                new Guid("4253876A-3556-11E1-BC17-B7184924019B")
            }.ToList(),

            EligiableCategories = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2DA62E3A-3556-11E1-8A0A-9B184924019B", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "35830042-3556-11E1-BCDC-A6184924019B", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3D07EBAC-3556-11E1-8943-B6184924019B", Text = "item 3" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "4253876A-3556-11E1-BC17-B7184924019B", Text = "item 4" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(
        x => x.SelectedEligiableCategories, 
        Model.EligiableCategories,  
        new { @class = "eligibleCategoryListBox" }
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have shown an example allowing to illustrate the problem, you could specify the selected item when building the `SelectList`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x[i].SelectedItem, 
    new SelectList(Model[i].Items, "Value", "Text", Model[i].SelectedItem)
)
```

The reason a value was not preselected was because you were binding the dropdownlist to a list of properties (`x => x[i].SelectedItem`) whereas in my example I was using a simple property.

And if you wanted to do this with the ListBoxFor helper you could use the following:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    x => x[i].SelectedItems, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model[i].Items, "Value", "Text", Model[i].SelectedItems)
)
```

The `SelectedItems` property becomes a collection and we use a `MultiSelectList` instead of a `SelectList`.

Comment: It looks pretty much what I have. I wonder why it does not work for me.

Comment: @chobo2, I don't know, I have showed a working version. Maybe you would like, the same way I did, provide a full example illustrating your problem. View model, controller (with hardcoded values) and view would be welcome to allow people reproducing the issue and hopefully helping you resolve it.

Comment: Ok I updated my post. It is actually happening with my dropdowns as well(so I made a hardcoded example of this).

Comment: @chobo2, thank you. Now your question is much more clear. I have updated my answer to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Interesting. So if you are just making one you can use the simple property and it will figure it out. But if you need a collection like I did then you need to specify the the selected list collection again so it has something compare it against?

Comment: @chobo2, yes, that's how those helpers are designed.

Comment: where do you define i? x => x[i].SelectedItems

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor
```

instead of this

```
@Html.ListBoxFor
```

Using the DropDownListFor will NOT help you with multiple values, whatever you do and no matter what your model is. Once you use ListBoxFor ... it will automatically just work !