# add checked checkboxes to list in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox

I'm working on a C# Application, where users can post jokes.
These jokes can have multiple categories, like one-liner or chuck norris.
So in my view for creating a joke i have multiple checkboxes for the categories.

Currently, when i create a joke, i have to give a list parameter with all the categories in it.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>CreateJokeViewModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JokeTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JokeTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JokeTitle)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JokeText)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JokeText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JokeText)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.categories)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <table>
    @using (var db = new Witze.Context())
    {

        foreach (Witze.Categorie categorie in db.Categories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox(categorie.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.Label(categorie.Name)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

        </table>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

ViewModel:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int UserId { get; set; }

[Required]
public string JokeTitle { get; set; }

[Required]
public string JokeText { get; set; }

[Required]
public HashSet<Categorie> categories { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateJokeViewModel viewModel)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string> { "ThisIsACategorie" };
    var user = db.User.Single(u => u.UserId == viewModel.UserId);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Logik.CreateJoke(viewModel.JokeTitle, viewModel.JokeText, user.UserId, list);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("witze", "user", new { userid = viewModel.UserId });
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So i want all the checked categories to be in the list.
I'm pretty new to MVC and i don't quite seem to find an answer...

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696358/how-to-show-multiple-selected-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-listboxfor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So i want all the checked categories to be in the list.

With little change in the ViewModel, you can get the checked values on submit as shown below -

Let your Models be like this -

```
public class CheckboxlistViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string JokeTitle { get; set; }
    public string JokeText { get; set; }
    public List<Categorie> categories { get; set; }
}

public class Categorie
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Observe that there is a property IsSelected associated with Categorie ViewModel. This property helps us to persist checkbox selection when form is submitted.

Now the action which renders the form is as follows -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CheckboxlistViewModel model = new CheckboxlistViewModel();
        model.categories = new List<Categorie>();
        model.categories.Add(new Categorie() { Category = "Chuck Norris", IsSelected = false });
        model.categories.Add(new Categorie() { Category = "One Liner", IsSelected = false });
        return View(model);
    }
```

And form is as shown below -

```
    @model MVC.Controllers.CheckboxlistViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Checkboxlist",FormMethod.Post))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.categories.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.categories[i].Category)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.categories[i].IsSelected) @Html.Label(Model.categories[i].Category)
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
    </div>
```

Now when we click the submit button it will hit below Action -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(CheckboxlistViewModel model)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

And if we check the returned model we get selected checkboxes as boolean values as shown below.
[image]

**NOTE:** If you want to persist Checkbox text, then add hiddenfield for Category field in the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much =)
It almost works as i want it.
Could you explain me your Note? I don't know where exactly i have to add hiddenfield, to persist Ceckbox text...
I would be greatful =)

Comment: @WTFisOssi, you have to add the Hiddenfield in the for loop where we are creating CheckBoxFor. And this hiddenfield is to persist Checkbox text. Or else you will be getting null (as shown in screenshot).

Comment: I'm sorry, i think im just plain stupid. I still don't know what i have to do so that I don't get null... Could you give me a code sample for that?

Comment: @WTFisOssi, I updated my answer with `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.categories[i].Category)` in the for loop. Please check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time =) Works flawless.
I would upvote your answer, but i don't have enaugh reputation yet...

Comment: @WTFisOssi, I am glad I solved your problem. I think with 15 reputation, you can upvote :-).

Comment: I am trying to do something similar; I got the error - CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this month ago and i wanted the same thing you want and i found a solution to it. go to this site it has perfect solution to it
 http://www.overpie.com/jquery/articles/jquery-get-selected-checkboxes

Up my answer if it works :)