# Passing a List from View to Controller in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass a complex data structure from Controller to View and Back to Controller which contains Lists. I can see the list items in View. I want to edit those and send it back to the controller. I am able to edit some properties but for lists, I am getting null value in the controller.

Here is an example (simulation) of what I am trying to achieve:

Consider Model -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FeedBack { get; set; }
        public List<ScoreCard> ScoreCards;
    }

    public class ScoreCard
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Marks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller -

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new StudentViewModel();
        model.StudentId = "Some Student";
        model.ScoreCards = new List<ScoreCard>
        {
            new ScoreCard()
            {
                Marks = "0",
                Subject = "English"
            },
            new ScoreCard()
            {
                Marks = "0",
                Subject = "Maths"
            }
        };
        return View("View", model);
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitScore(StudentViewModel model)
    {
        /* Some Code */
    }
}
```

View -

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.StudentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitScore", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DisplayName(@Model.StudentId)<br />
    <label>Comment:</label><br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeedBack, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", id = @Model.FeedBack} })<br />
    for (var i = 0; i < @Model.ScoreCards.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayName(@Model.ScoreCards[i].Subject) <br/>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ScoreCards[i].Marks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = 0, id = @Model.ScoreCards[i].Marks} })<br />
    }
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

When I run the application -

[image]

When I click submit, I am able to see `model.FeedBack` but the list is set to null.

[image]

Something similar is achieved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875083/add-checked-checkboxes-to-list-in-viewmodel) & it's answer; I am not sure what exactly I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you send no input for the `Subject` . You'll need a hidden input for that along with any other value you want returned to the controller when the form is posted. Also a simple text box should work for the marks.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitScore", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DisplayName(@Model.StudentId)<br />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentId)
    <label>Comment:</label><br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeedBack, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", id = @Model.FeedBack} })<br />
    for (var i = 0; i < @Model.ScoreCards.Count; i++) {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCards[i].Subject)
        @Html.DisplayName(@Model.ScoreCards[i].Subject) <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ScoreCards[i].Marks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = 0} })<br />
    }
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Finally you need to use properties in order for the model binding to work. You currently have `ScoreCards` as a field so update it to a property.

```
public class StudentViewModel {
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FeedBack { get; set; }
    public List<ScoreCard> ScoreCards { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: oh.. So we cannot assign ids to these fields.

Comment: @Vikram the html helpers do that for you automatically anyway. Unless you need a id for some specific reason there really is no need to manually set it